# Order a std::vector of structs by two fields in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, data-structures, stdvector

I have a `std::vector` of structs in order to store `x0` and `y0` values.
I would like to be able to sort the vector items by ordering them starting from the points with the lower `x0` and `y0` values.
At the moment, I'm only able to sort them by considering only `x0` or `y0` values.

```
    struct Coordinate
    {
        double x0 = 0.0;
        double x1 = 0.0;

        Coordinate(double paramx0, double paramy0) : x0(paramx0), y0(paramy0) {}
    };

 std::vector<Coordinate> coords;
 std::vector<Coordinate> coords_x;
 std::vector<Coordinate> coords_y;  

    bool compareByLength_x(const Coordinate &a, const Coordinate &b)
    {
        return a.x0 < b.x0;
    }

    bool compareByLength_y(const Coordinate &a, const Coordinate &b)
    {
        return a.y0 < b.y0;
    }

    // ... storing values in the vector and then sort it..

    std::sort(coords.begin(), coords.end(), compareByLength_x);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < coords.size(); ++i)
    {
       cout << i << " X[0]: " << coords[i].x0 << " Y[0]: " << coords[i].y0 << endl; 
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;    
    parallel_y(coords.size(), coords);    
    cout << "\n" <<endl;


    std::sort(coords.begin(), coords.end(), compareByLength_y);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < coords.size(); ++i)
    {
       cout << i << " X[0]: " << coords[i].x0 << " Y[0]: " << coords[i].y0 << endl; 
    }

    cout << "\n" << endl;    
    parallel_x(coords.size(), coords);    
    cout << "\n" <<endl;
```

For example, if the vector contains:

```
125, 140
125, 32
125, 196
164, 38
10, 38
```

then it should become:

```
10, 38
125, 32
125, 140
125, 196
164, 38
```

by checking the lowest `x0` value at first and then, for the same `x0` values, looking for the lowest `y0` values.

How can I implement it? Can I use a single function?

Answer (score 0):

Yes a single function. Just code the logic you described perfectly correctly above

```
bool compareByLength_x_and_y(const Coordinate &a, const Coordinate &b)
{
    return a.x0 < b.x0 || (a.x0 == b.x0 && a.y0 < b.y0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C++11 [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) from `<tuple>` can be used for convenience to implement lexicographical comparisons involving many members:

```
bool compareByLength_xy(const Coordinate& a, const Coordinate& b)
{
    return std::tie(a.x0,a.y0) < std::tie(b.x0,b.y0);
}
```

The trick is to construct tuples and tuples already implement the desired comparison. Note that the link above has an example where `std::tie` is used for exactly that.